# Install mysqlclient-python in Docker

Tags: linux, debian, python, mysql, docker

I am trying install mysqlclient-python in docker with Debian 8 
but when I run python3 setup.py install 
I get error:

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/_mysql.o -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -ldl -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/_mysql.cpython-34m.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I tryed install various packages (openssl, crypto++, libmysqlclient-dev, mysql-client,...) but nothing helped me.. 
Do you know what exactly I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install the [`libssl-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/fr/jessie/libssl-dev) package avallaible on the security repo , the following url should exist on your `sources.list`

```
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main
```

or

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
```

Run :

```
apt-get update && apt-get install libssl-dev
apt-get install python3-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: I'll add that `build-essential` is another library that can cause this when building a docker image

Run:
`apt-get install build-essential`